# Have to parse "appreciate it if."

Tags: objects, dummy-pronouns

> I will appreciate it if you can help me.

Someone says "it" is the dummy object, with the if-clause being the real one. I doubt it , because if that is the case, "if" can be replaced with "whether", which actually doesn't work.

So how do you parse this construction?

Comment: *If* and *whether* are not synonyms in the first place. The sentence *whether you are hungry, you should eat* doesn't make any sense—and it has nothing to do with a dummy it.

Comment: If it is a object clause，whether and if are interchangeable, like "I doubt **whether/if** she is correct".

Comment: Are you suggesting "if", in the original post, is adverbial? If that is the case, I should be able to front the "if ", as "if you can help me, I will appreciate it". Is this movement correct?

Comment: "I'll appreciate it if you **could** help me (about it)" sounds nicer to my ear, though a non native's.

Comment: *I [usually **would**, not **will**] appreciate **you / your helping me***, where your version's ***it*** corresponds to the highlighted element (***what*** you would appreciate, which is "something" - a noun). Or more precisely in your case, ***your being able to help***, your "capacity" to do this).

Comment: @Robbyzhu I would certainly not say that *I doubt whether she is correct* is idiomatic. It's *understandable*, but it's not something that somebody would normally say. That's not how the word is normally used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would normally say:

> I *would* appreciate it if you *could* help me.

As you are using an 'if' clause, your appreciation is only relevant *if* they are able to help, which they may not be able to. If anything, it is more polite to use "would" and "could" here - saying you *will* appreciate something only if they *can* help is essentially like saying you *won't* appreciate if they don't.

Comment: Right. would not will, in most cases.